# Emacs: How can I set Meta- with 2 letter combinations?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I want to be able to hold M-a and hit 'j' once to execute one command, without letting go of M-a (This way I hold M-a and hit 'j' each time I want to move back a word).

I tried the two following codes in my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-a-j") 'backward-word)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-a M-j") 'backward-word)
```

I am not familiar with Lisp. I'm going to do the same for forward-word with 'l'.

More info : Okay so `M-a M-j` works, but only if I let go of `M-a` after each time I want to execute the command. I want to be able to hold it and hit `j` to make it execute each time without ever letting go of `M-a`. Also, I found out `M-a-j` is not actually valid.

I already disabled the command on `M-a`, saved my file, and loaded with `M-x eval-buffer` (I know that's working).

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that you have your keyboard `Alt` key acting as Emacs `Meta`.  Holding down a modifier key such as `Alt` and hitting keys such as `a` and `j` sequentially corresponds to `(kbd "M-a M-j")`.  Did that not do what you request?

However, by default, `M-a` is bound to a key, so it cannot act as a prefix key.  You need to first do this, before making your `(kbd "M-a M-j")` binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-a") nil)
```

Comment: Yes, Alt is my Meta key, and I set M-a to nil (before that code). (kbd "M-a M-j") did not work, it would say it's undefined.

I was using "M-x eval-buffer" to load it, but since it was "undefined", I decided to close and reopen emacs. It didn't load my settings (.emacs file) and I opened my .emacs to find it was blank. Now I'm gonna add all my code back to it, but why did it do that? (I'm obviously new to emacs). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm. What I described works for me. Dunno why your init file got emptied. Please show the exact error message you got, instead of "*it would say it's undefined*" (dunno what the two "*it*"s are). Suggestion: try one thing at a time - try to work on just this question, *without an init file* (i.e., use `emacs -Q`). No sense trying to debug a lot of unknown (to us) stuff. One thing at a time.

Comment: Okay. That error was my fault. Now it works, but not how I wanted it to be working. I added a bit more info on my original post.

Comment: Sorry, but what you say you want is exactly what I get by unbinding `M-a` and then binding `M-a M-j`. If `Alt` acts for you as a `Meta` key then you should be able to hold it down and then hit `a` followed by `j`, then release `Alt`. Again: what happens when you start from `emacs -Q` (no init file), and you just do those two things (unbind `M-a` and bind `M-a M-j`?